# particles constrained problem, Animating particles in cycles Blender 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, particles

So I just set an animation of a saw blade sparking off an object to render, but the animation png results have the particles constrained to a small area, but if i render a single still the particles work as intended. Can anyone help me with this issue? Bellow are images of the animation and still renders.

[image: Image from animation with issue]

[image: Still without issue]

Comment: Can you upload your blend file?

Comment: Hi there I solved this issue, it was to do with hair not being ticked in the render options. Cheers, Tom.